# How to prevent re-render GoogleMap API when state changes?

Tags: react-google-maps-api

I have used Google Map API from '@react-google-map/api' & the problem is that map was re-rendered when its center point changes by state update. Then, how do I solve this ..?

When I update the center of the map to be change in the redux state, the map won't be re-render.